# Does powershell have associative arrays?

Tags: arrays, powershell, associative-array

I am writing a function that returns an id, name pair.

I would like to do something like

```
$a = get-name-id-pair()
$a.Id
$a.Name
```

like is possible in javascript.  Or at least

```
$a = get-name-id-pair()
$a["id"]
$a["name"]
```

like is possible in php.  Can I do that with powershell?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

also

```
$a = @{'foo'='bar'}
```

or

```
$a = @{}
$a.foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: Old comment, but how would you loop through an associative array via a foreach loop?

Comment: $associativeArray=@{

    Jane=1

    Tom=2

    Harry=3
}


foreach($key in $associativeArray.Keys) {
    $key
}

foreach($item in $associativeArray.GetEnumerator()) {
    "{0}={1}" -f $item.Key, $item.Value
}×Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.×Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.×Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: `$associativeArray=@{ Jane=1 Tom=2 Harry=3 }` gives me `Unexpected token 'Tom=2' in expression or statement.` what works is `$associativeArray=@{ Jane=1; Tom=2; Harry=3 }`

Comment: @stib, each value must either be on a seperate line (a simple return will do), or use a delimiter as you did. Seperate lines makes for easier readability.

Comment: for anyone who wants a bit more dynamic keys:

$Data         = @{};
$Key           = 'foo';
$Data.$Key = 'bar';

Answer (score 25):

Yes.  Use the following syntax to create them

```
$a = @{}
$a["foo"] = "bar"
```

Answer (score 22):

Will add also the way to iterate through hashtable, as I was looking for the solution and did not found one...

```
$c = @{"1"="one";"2"="two"} 
foreach($g in $c.Keys){write-host $c[$g]} #where key = $g and value = $c[$g]
```

Comment: The only answer that mentions the semicolon `;` separator.

Comment: @Ivan Temchenko & @Maggyero, This is NOT A RELIABLE ANSWER, if you don't think so, then tell me why this code ```$shortcuts = @{'MyDocuments'='Personal';'MyComputer'='MyComputer'}
Foreach($shortcut in $shortcuts.Keys) {
    Echo "\`$shortcut:$shortcut"; Echo "\`$shortcuts[\`$shortcut]:$shortcuts[$shortcut]"
}
Read-Host``` doesn't give me  `MyDocuments` as key and `Personal` as it's value in the `$shortcuts` array ? (In the above code block, add newlines to make the code block work, it's just the limitation of comments that code blocks are not styled properly)...

Comment: @Viky Dev The problem is that within a string you should use $() for your expression:
`"$($shortcuts[$shortcut])"` will give the expected result. In your example, Powershell is evaluating it as a Hashtable, a [, then a string, and another ]. When you enclose all of that in $() then it evaluates it as a powershell expression instead. I've just settled on always enclosing variables/expressions withing a string in $().

Answer (score 9):

```
#Define an empty hash
$i = @{}

#Define entries in hash as a number/value pair - ie. number 12345 paired with Mike is   entered as $hash[number] = 'value'

$i['12345'] = 'Mike'  
$i['23456'] = 'Henry'  
$i['34567'] = 'Dave'  
$i['45678'] = 'Anne'  
$i['56789'] = 'Mary'  

#(optional, depending on what you're trying to do) call value pair from hash table as a variable of your choosing

$x = $i['12345']

#Display the value of the variable you defined

$x

#If you entered everything as above, value returned would be:

Mike
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this for keeping track of sites/directories when working on multiple domains. It is possible to initialise the array when declaring it rather than adding each entry separately:

```
$domain = $env:userdnsdomain
$siteUrls = @{ 'TEST' = 'http://test/SystemCentre' 
               'LIVE' = 'http://live/SystemCentre' }

$url = $siteUrls[$domain]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PS C:\> $a = @{}                                                      
PS C:\> $a.gettype()                                                  

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            

-------- -------- ----                                     --------            

True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

So a hashtable is an associative array.  Ohhh.

Or:

```
PS C:\> $a = [Collections.Hashtable]::new()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Create From JSON String**

```
$people= '[
{
"name":"John", 
"phone":"(555) 555-5555"
},{
"name":"Mary", 
"phone":"(444) 444-4444"
}
]';

# Convert String To Powershell Array
$people_obj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $people;

# Loop through them and get each value by key.
Foreach($person in $people_obj ) {
    echo $person.name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
function get-faqentry { "meaning of life?", 42 }
$q, $a = get-faqentry
```

Not associative array, but equally as useful.

-Oisin

Comment: simpler will be
`$q, $a = @("meaning of life?", 42)`